# Rails rake task - parsing CSV file and importing if it doesn't already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to create a new rake task in rails 3.

I have two csv files (gas.csv & elec.csv) with usage data that gets updated every fifteen minutes from an SQL database.
The format of the csv's are as follows (I don't have control over this):

```
MeterID,RoundedTimeStamp,Value,Register
165,31/01/2012 00:00,1200,0
165,28/02/2012 00:15,1201,0
165,31/03/2012 00:30,1199,0
```

The csv's are updated on a monthly basis with new values, and I want to write a rake import task to import the files into relevant parts of a model, Usage(month, elec, gas). So far I've got the following for the elec import, which isn't really working:

```
require 'csv'
desc "Importing Usage data from CSV file"
task import: :environment do

    file = ".../elec.csv"

    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
            Usage.find_or_create_by_month({
                month: row[1],
                elec: row[2]
            })
    end
end
```

When I run rake:import from the console, it imports the elec usage data just fine, but doesn't skip over duplicates. Is there a way I can import this file without duplicates, and also a way to do the same for the gas data?

Note: I know it's better practice to use first_or_create rather than find_or_create, but this wouldn't work with _by_month.

Cheers!

Comment: `where(month: row[1]).first_or_create`, find_or_create should be on the list of deprecated methos for Rails 4.

Comment: Yeah I saw that on APIdock, I it that way first, but it didn't work either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.where(month: row[1]).first_or_create do |user|
  user.elec = row[2]
end
```

More info at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it creates new records even if they already exist (much the same functionality as my own one).

Comment: @KevL, did you try this on its own? I tried on the console and it worked just like the example provided. I'll advise you reduce the problem to the minimum and see where it fails.

Comment: Ah - I see where I was going wrong. The RoundedTimeStamp is in DateTime format, and my month column is in date format, so I fixed it by adding `month: row[1].to_date)`. Thanks! Do you know is it faster to do it your way, with `usage.elec = row[2]`, or just having it as `.first_or_create(elec: row[2])`?

Comment: No, but if I were setting a single property I'll use the inline version without the block.

Comment: Also - is there a way to do this simulataneously for both csv's, or must I separate them into separate CSV.foreach methods? Or would I be better off setting them up as separate rake tasks? Apologies for all the questions, I'm very new to rails.

Comment: Two foreach, don't repeat yourself and  use a method or a lambda. You could always append the contents of one file to the other, before processing and do a single foreach, but it will be more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [`Upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert):

```
require 'upsert'
require 'active_support/core_ext' # you'll already have this in Rails
# ...
u = Upsert.new Usage.connection, Usage.table_name
# ...
CSV.foreach('elec.csv', headers: :first_row) do |row|
  date = Date.parse row['RoundedTimeStamp']
  selector = { meter_id: row['MeterID'], month: date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
  setter = { elec: row['Value'] }
  u.row selector, setter
end
CSV.foreach('gas.csv', headers: :first_row) do |row|
  date = Date.parse row['RoundedTimeStamp']
  selector = { meter_id: row['MeterID'], month: date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
  setter = { gas: row['Value'] }
  u.row selector, setter
end
```

If your "month" column is a string field, then this will work. If it's a real date field, then you might try just using the first of every month:

```
date.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, "cannot load such file -- upsert"? Also, yep I'm fairly sure I'm right with the row[1], as the header is "RoundedTimeStamp".

Comment: add "upsert" to your Gemfile?

Comment: Ah feck...fairly obvious! Any idea how I could do this to import the gas for existing months also??

Comment: you just need 2 `CSV.foreach` blocks, one for each csv file. in each one, just make sure you set the selector carefully to be the "name" field

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both bits of code now, and they don't add anything to the database (throwing no errors). Even if I destroy_all usages, they still add nothing? Here's the code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/PAD38JTA

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Unfortunately it's still not importing anything. I also don't have a meter_id attribute in my usages table. Apart from that though, it's not importing anything from the file, still a blank table with no errors. Any ideas??